# Excel macro - merging fields and adding a value

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I have written a piece of code, it copies the data from the entire cells and pastes this into another file.

```
    Select Case Range("A2").Value
    Case 3
        Sheets("Info").Select
        Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Design").Range("B1")
    End Select
```

Example of what I'm trying to do;

```
1.xls
Cell A1: Black Jack
Cell A2: 3
```

This gets copied and pasted in

```
2.xls
Cell B1: Black Jack
```

Now how can I insert the information from A2 into B1 aswell to get something along the lines of

```
Cell B1: Black Jack - 3x
```

Also the source formatting gets changed, it should be Century Gothic, 12 but changes to Calibri, 11.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use copy. Be explicit like this:

```
Sheets("Design").Range("B1").Value = Range("A1").Value & " - " & Range("A2").Value & "x"
```

This will only copy the values and no fonts will be harmed in the process.

Comment: No this is value only. As you are putting multiple values together you can't copy formats across as there's only one format per cell; you'd have to format each bit manually in the VBA to make a whole string which was formatted correctly. It might just work as is for you, but if it doesn't, you'd have to format appropriately in the statement above. e.g. & Format(Range("A2").Value, "0.00")